# Delay in Contact form and Subscribe for - SMTP

Tags: php, smtp

I'm writing this query after searching insanely online. I'm not a geek so I have limited understanding of technical stuff.
My Problem - I'm on VPS with Hostinger and installed Cyberpanel with cent os 7. I have nearly 6 websites under that hosting. Most of them are wordpress and laravel. All the sites have contact forms which I've built either through Elementor or Wordpress plugins or readymade smtp script on Laravel. My issue is all the contact form from all sites work really slow. I mean the submission takes almost couple of minutes. The plugin provider says its the hosting issue and the hosting provider says otherwise. I tried searching and editing PHP config file and with gmail but couldn't  get through.. Can somebody help me with this issue and/or help to setup Gmail.

Thank you.

Comment: Sending outbound emails from a shared hosting provider is always a crap shoot, as they often impose severe restrictions to avoid abuse. I'd recommend an API-based mailer like Mailgun or Amazon SES.

Comment: I'm on 4gigs VPS server.. Could you tell my the steps to get that installed.. Thank you.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake, I saw "VPS" and read "shared hosting" heh. What SMTP host are you submitting to?

Comment: Earlier it was the default smtp settings.. I tried changing it to gmail i.e. smtp.gmail.com and and with port 587 for TLS

Comment: It takes a couple of minutes for the form page to submit the message? Or it takes a couple of minutes for the recipient to receive the message in their inbox?

Comment: After clicking on submit it takes forever for the page to say that the message is sent.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution.. Please help

Answer (score 0):

So.. I figured out.. I guess it was my hosting provider.. HOSTINGER!! I moved couple of my sites to Google Cloud Platform.. And my sites work flawlessly.. No Hiccups at all.. So the Mantra is GCP!! Thank you so much for your response..